# What is the distribution of $\sup\limits_{t\geq 0}( B_t-xt)$

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I would like to find the distribution of $\sup\limits_{t\geq 0}( B_t-xt)$, where $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Wiener process and $x > 0$.

I don't know how to begin.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Use Girsanov's theorem.